# How to get value from inputted date/time field in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, date, time

Here's my code.

```
var reqshdate = get_req_sh_date();

function get_req_sh_date() {
    var reqshdateField = document.getElementById("A0.R0.ZDate_12");
    if (!reqshdateField) {
        return "[Requested Ship Date]"; 
    } //field isn't on layout

    if (typeof reqshdateField.innerHTML == 'undefined' ) {
        return "[Requested Ship Date]";
    } // field is blank

    var returnString = removeHTML(reqshdateField.innerHTML);

    return returnString;
}
```

When there's a value on the date/time field, it displays the value. But when there's no date/time inputted, it should display [Requested Ship Date]. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aupnnupg/), the code is below:

```
function get_req_sh_date() {
    var reqshdateField = document.getElementById("A0.R0.ZDate_12");
    if (!reqshdateField || reqshdateField.value === "") return "[Requested Ship Date]";
    return reqshdateField.value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried it but the return is undefined when the date/time field is empty. When it has date/time value, the return is still undefined.

Comment: What's your browser version? I ever tested on chrome